# Optimize PowerShell Performance and Memory Consumption

Tags: powershell, csv, out-of-memory, audit

The PowerShell script below queries the Security event log on one or more servers for events with id 4663. When trying to retrieve all audit events for event id 4663 with the following code the computer throws the following exception: how can we to optimize this PowerShell?
So I just want to fetch security event log based on specific AD Users instead of all of users. Otherwise I want to retrieve what I need.

[image]
[image]

```
$server = "HOSTNAME"
$out = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
$out.AppendLine("ServerName,EventID,TimeCreated,UserName,File_or_Folder,AccessMask")
$ns = @{e = "http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event"}
foreach ($svr in $server)
    {    $evts = Get-WinEvent -computer $svr -FilterHashtable @{logname="security";id="4663"} -oldest

    foreach($evt in $evts)
        {
        $xml = [xml]$evt.ToXml()

        $SubjectUserName = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath "//e:Data[@Name='SubjectUserName']/text()" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value

        $ObjectName = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath "//e:Data[@Name='ObjectName']/text()" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value

        $AccessMask = Select-Xml -Xml $xml -Namespace $ns -XPath "//e:Data[@Name='AccessMask']/text()" | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Value

        $out.AppendLine("$($svr),$($evt.id),$($evt.TimeCreated),$SubjectUserName,$ObjectName,$AccessMask")

        Write-Host $svr
        Write-Host $evt.id,$evt.TimeCreated,$SubjectUserName,$ObjectName,$AccessMask

        }
    }
$out.ToString() | out-file -filepath C:\TEMP\4663Events.csv
```

Comment: To optimize performance, first measure it: the slowest part by far is `Get-WinEvent`. Now you can start looking for answers how to speed it up. What I know is that on a local computer `Get-EventLog Security -InstanceId 4663` is 100 or 1000 times faster. Try testing it in your environment. If it's also slow, consider remote PS job execution so that `Get-EventLog` is executed locally on remote computers and results are sent back to yours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refactor the code so that the stringbuilder contents are flushed every now and then. This keeps its size more manageable. Like so,

```
$out = New-Object System.Text.StringBuilder
$out.AppendLine("ServerName,EventID,TimeCreated,UserName,File_or_Folder,AccessMask")
foreach($evt in $evts) {
    $xml = [xml]$evt.ToXml()
    ...
    $out.AppendLine("$($svr),$($evt.id),$($evt.TimeCreated),$SubjectUserName,$ObjectName,$AccessMask")
    # If the stringbuffer is large enough, flush its contents to disk
    # and start filling empty buffer again
    if($out.length -ge 100MB) {
        $out.ToString() | out-file -filepath C:\TEMP\4663Events.csv -append
        $out.Clear()
    }
}
# Remember to flush the buffer so that stuff that wasn't flushed in the
# foreach loop is saved as well
$out.ToString() | out-file -filepath C:\TEMP\4663Events.csv -append
```

**Edit:**

As the error is coming from `Out-LineOutput`, which is an [internal cmdlet](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849734.aspx), it might be about the shell memory settings. You could try increasing the maximum memory per shell to, say 2 GB. Like so,

```
Set-Item .\MaxMemoryPerShellMB 2048
```

The MS Scripting Guys blog has a [detailed article](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/30/learn-how-to-configure-powershell-memory/) about configuring the limits

Comment: thanks unfortunately I am still facing same issue So when running powershell code memory usage is growing and then I am getting "out of memory"

Comment: thanks again Finally How can we to fetch security event log based on specific AD Users instead of all of users?

Comment: That would be another a question worth its own. If the memory problem is solved, please check this as answered and open another for filtering log by user.